# Dynamic crm 2016 rest api node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to connect to crm 2016 with node js rest api.
I'm trying to do a simple retrieve and i don't get any error message.
Please maybe someone know about library that can help me with this issuse?

Comment: Share the code to assist you

Answer (score 2):

To access Dynamics CRM 2016 via REST APIs you should know your Organisation Service Base URL. You can retrieve the URL by following below steps:

```
login to CRM -> Settings -> Customizations -> Developer Resource -> Service Root URL
```

Sample of Service Root URL  : https://xxx.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/

Now, you can use this URL to access all the resources of Dynamics CRM with OAuth authentication.
You can use `Request` node module to access the Dynamics CRM resources like account, contact, etc with NodeJS.

Sample URL to retrieve all Contacts from Dynamics CRM as below:

```
GET https://xxx.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/contacts
Headers:
Authorization - Bearer <Access_Token>
Accept - application/json
```

[image]

Also, please take care of proxy as well if you are in secured network.